# How do I converge to and fro, between two numbers?

Tags: algorithm, animation

I'm trying to animate a man running:

Frames 1 to 5 = man leaning into run.
Frames 6 to 15 = man running a single step

```
frame = 1           
frame +=1         //frames progress forwards at rate of 1 frame 

function run(){
   if(frame>15){     //at frame 15: man has completed leaning into run and completed one 'running' cycle
       frame -=2      //frames now start to go backwards at rate of (1-2=)-1 frame
       if(frame<6){   //until they reach frame 6 (beginning of running animation)
           frame +=2  //frames start to progress forwards again at rate of (2-2+1=)+1 frame again
```

My method is really bad and seems to be only capable of going forwards then backwards ONCE between 15 and 6.

Does anyone know how I can bounce between these two numbers indefinitely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reaching frame = 15 and beginning your trip downward, you hit a condition (14) where neither of your IF statements is true.  So your frame neither increments nor decrements.  Stuck.

A possible better solution would be to maintain a variable called myDirection which toggles periodically between 1 and -1.  That is, set myDirection = -1 when you hit 15, and set myDirection = 1 when you hit 6.   Then, your iterative statement could always say  `frame = frame + myDirection` and it would always be doing something -- you'd never be stuck doing nothing.

Comment: ah whoops I knew there was some giant gaping hole in my logic.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so using LesterDove's + schnaader's useful tips I've managed:

```
int step=1

function run(){
    frame += step
    if(frame>15){ step = -1}
    if(frame<6){ step = 1}
}
```

and it works great guys. Thanks again!

Comment: Well done. Note you won't need the `forward` boolean at all, it should be enough to just change `step` inside the `if` statements.